# Put several different image collections into a new image collection at different bands and download the new image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I have several different image collections and they align with each other well. How can I put them into one image at different bands as a new image collection? In this case, I want to download the new image.

Below is one example show the structure in my mind on the GEE Python API.

```py
start_date = '2018-12-9'
end_date = '2018-12-10'

# Call those 6 image collections within the same period.
c1 = ee.ImageCollection('xxxxxxxx').filterDate(start_date,end_date)
c2 = ee.ImageCollection('yyyyyyyy').filterDate(start_date,end_date)
c3 = ee.ImageCollection('zzzzzzzz').filterDate(start_date,end_date)
c4 = ee.ImageCollection('vvvvvvvv').filterDate(start_date,end_date)
c5 = ee.ImageCollection('bbbbbbbb').filterDate(start_date,end_date)
c6 = ee.ImageCollection('nnnnnnnn').filterDate(start_date,end_date)

# How to put these 6 image collections into one new image collection?
combined_img = 

# Download images.
out_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')
geemap.download_ee_image_collection(combined_img, out_dir)
```

Comment: There is already a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273676/merging-two-image-collection-into-one-with-two-bands-lst-and-ndvi?rq=1) for this, though it is in javascript.